# Can an interface be a descendant?

Tags: c#

I was wondering: can an `interface` inherit from another class?

I'm trying to let an interface inherit from the `MarshalByRefObject`.

My intent is that all classes implementing the interface also inherit from that class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it cannot.
An interface can only specify other interfaces that must be implemented. This is done by using the same syntax as inheritance, but it's something different.

You could use an abstract class instead that inherits from `MarshalByRefObject` and and requires your interfaces to be implemented.

Depending on how you need to enforce your requirement, generic constraints might help, too. For generic type parameters, you can set class constraints, like `class Argh<T> where T : MarshalByRefObject, ISomeInterface`.

Answer (score 3):

An interface cannot inherit from a class. In order to do that C# would need to support multiple inheritance of implementation which is currently not supported.

Imagine if you could derive an interface, `IMyInterface`, from a class, `MyClass`. Then when you come to declare another class that implements that interface, you would have to write something like:

```
public class MyImplementingClass: MyBaseClass, IMyInterface
```

But that implies multiple inheritance of implementation since you are inheriting from both `MyBaseClass` and `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

No, but an interface can inherit from another interface.

Answer (score 2):

No, an interface cannot have any implementation, so it can't inherit from a class. However you can make an **abstract class** that inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`.

Answer (score 2):

No. Classes can implement interfaces. Its not the other way round.

1. Class can inherit class and implement interface.
2. Interface can implement only interface but can neither inherit nor implement classes.